# NSDateFormatter producing (null) SQLite and iOS 5.1

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, datetime

Maybe somebody can help explain why I am getting a null value when converting a string to a date.  It all looks right but I'm obviously missing something here.

Some background:

This iPad app will be used in different countries and I will need to do a calculation on the date to see if 90 days have passed since a user last logged in.

I have a SQLite Database with a DateLastIn field set as TEXT

My Object has a DateLastIn property set as NSDate

When populating my record object I set up a NSDateFormatter as such..

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];  // SQLite default date format
```

Then I read in the DateLastIn (Using FMDB wrapper for SQLite).

```
        // test SQLite as String
        NSString *testDate = [results stringForColumn:@"DateLastIn"];
        NSLog(@"DateLastIn straight from DB (string) shows %@", testDate);
```

Result: 
**DateLastIn straight from DB (string) shows 2012-04-23 18:20:51**

All is good so far.  Next I test converting this to an NSDate object e.g

```
        NSDate *aDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
        aDate = [formatter dateFromString:testDate];
        NSLog(@"Using formmater on string date results in: %@", aDate);
```

Result:
**Using formmater on string date results in: (null)**

I have tried DATETIME in SQLite, I've tried using NSString in my object instead of NSDate and seem to be going around in circles.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSDateFormatter` uses the [format patterns from the Unicode Technical Standard #35](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

For the hour format, you need `HH` (Hour [0-23]) not `hh` (Hour [1-12]).

Comment: oh wow, no wonder I didn't spot it, was looking for something much more sinister!.  Works a treat, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I changed your date format to HH not hh and it works. Here is my test code....

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];  // SQLite default date format


// test SQLite as String
NSString *testDate = @"2012-04-23 18:20:51";



NSDate *aDate = [formatter dateFromString:testDate];

NSLog(@"Using formmater on string date results in: %@", aDate);
```

Comment: Thanks for that, much appreciated to both you and Daniel.